# How can I get log4j to use a log4j.xml file and not write to console when using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I'm helping a friend with a project.  He uses Spring; I am not.  I gave him a `log4j.xml` file I use to enable logging to a file in a `logs/` subdirectory.  He tried the `log4j.xml` but his app is ignoring it (doesn't react to its presence or absence), sending output to the console.  It appears Spring is auto-configuring `log4j` to do this.  We also tried `-Ddebug.log4j=true` to find discern more about `log4j`'s initialization when Spring is involved, but that parameter had no effect.

Comment: If the xml file is on classpath, it should pick. Make sure its on classpath.

Comment: @Rp- Do you mean literally the CLASSPATH (where JARs are found)?  Or should it be in some other resource path?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Log4j scan through classpath to find either log4j.properties or log4j.xml. If you prefer any other location or file name, you need to do some additional configuration. I will try to find a reference.

Comment: If you prefer a different path or different name you need to use `-Dlog4j.configuration=relative_path_to_file.xml`

Comment: @Rp- Your comments have proved helpful.  Can you put them in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad that it helped, I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, log4j doesn't make any assumptions about its configuration, it definitely expects either a configuration file or a programmatic configuration.

It scans through the classpath for `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml`. If you prefer a different path and different name, you need pass a system variable something like
`-Dlog4j.configuration=relative_path_to_file.xml`

Comment: what if the 'scans' find both log4j.properties and log4j.xml files?

Comment: @MinnieShi It prefers xml over properties if it found both. I could not find a reference, but this is what I observed when I had them both on my classpath sometime back in one of my previous projects.

Answer (score 0):

Right now in our project

we use below xml file

```
<appender name="EvolutionWebASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="logFileOut" />
</appender>

<appender name="logFileOut" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="C:/home/wasadmin/applogs/myproject/myproject.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="ALL" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d %-5p - [TXID: %X{TXID}] [UID: %X{UID}] [ORGOID: %X{ORGOID}] [UA_ORGOID: %X{UA_ORGOID}] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d %-5p - [TXID: %X{TXID}] [UID: %X{UID}] [ORGOID: %X{ORGOID}] [UA_ORGOID: %X{UA_ORGOID}] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="EvolutionWebASYNC" /> 
</root>
```

I hope it helps !!!

Comment: Thank you @Sanket. Not the particular answer I was looking for, but I appreciate your helpfulness.